# Can we capture line no of string occuring multiple times into variable(last occurance only)

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris

I want to capture line no of string "Job has completed" into variable. for that i am using below commmand

```
l1=$(awk '/Job has completed/{ print NR; exit }' /home/ctm/Desktop/swa*)
```

But string occurs multiple time in same file.So with help of above command I am able to capture its 1st appearance. Can we capture last appearance of string(line no into variable) .

Answer (score 1):

You can try out below command:

```
awk '{if ($2~"Job has completed") a=NR} END{print a}' your_file
```

We check every second occurence being "Job has completed" and we record the number of line. It is appended, so by the time we finish reading the file, it will be the last one.

You can also follow [this](http://cs.canisius.edu/ONLINESTUFF/PL_TUTORIALS/AWK/awk.examples)  link which has some great usage of awk.